# I would like to run py script that will allow me to interact with it in a console while its exectuing

Tags: python, interpreter

I hope my question is clear.

Here is a code example:

```
import threading,time

TICK=True

def tick():
    while TICK:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("tick")

thread = threading.Thread(target=tick)

thread.start()
```

I would like to execute that script and be able to use console that will pop up as an python interpreter with that code running in a background.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm I'm guessing I can just run a python with -i flag[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).